# Controlling movement of flying a vehicle with SceneKit

Tags: ios, 3d, core-animation, scenekit, game-physics

I currently have a scene which contains a central node at the root of the scene with earth-like geometry and a node representing a flying vehicle.

However I cannot find the right approach to control the movement of the vehicle. I need the ability to turn left and right while orbiting at a static altitude and speed.

I have tried many combinations of animations and physics body forces all leading to undesirable results.

The closest I've come is:

- Setting the pivot property of the vehicle to the centre of the scene
- Then setting an Action like below to control moving forward

  ```
  [_vehicleNode runAction:[SCNAction repeatActionForever:[SCNAction rotateByX:-1 y:0 z:0 duration:10.0]]];
  ```
- Then finally applying forces for turning left and right with

  ```
  [_vehicleNode.physicsBody applyTorque:SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, 1) impulse:YES];
  ```

However I cannot seem to set the pivot and/or position to the right value to get the desired result.

Edit: It appears as the above method would be the solution I'm looking for, however for some reason when I add geometry to the vehicle node, it's position in the scene graph gets changed dramatically. When I add hardcoded buttons to change it's position to where it belongs it appears correct for only that single frame then straight back to being in the middle of nowhere.

Edit 2: After replacing all geometry with a primitive sphere for testing the node is now rotating as intended but is now unaffected by physics forces appearing to ignore it's declaration as a dynamicBody.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve correctly, you can try this:

- add a first node to your scene, positioned at (0,0,0) and make it rotate forever along the Y axis using an `SCNAction`
- add your ship node as a child of the first node. Position it at (X,0,0) so that it orbits around the earth
- rotate your ship node along the X axis with an action or an animation

Comment: I may have been a bit unclear using orbit to explain the effect I am trying to achieve. When the vehicle rotates I need the direction of it's momentum to also change.